# nodeValue and indexOf doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/b1ekda2j/1/

my html

```
<dd>
    <br>作詞：汪峰
    <br>作曲：汪峰
    <br>
    <br>他們將你狠狠地遺棄在街口
    <br>流血的腦袋出現混亂的幻覺
    <br>你是否在懷疑你拼死的付出
    <br>是否再一次質疑堅守的信仰
```

my js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('br').each(function () {
        var nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
        console.log(nodeValue);
        if (nodeValue.indexOf(':') > -1) {
            $(this.nextSibling).remove();
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

I want to remove `<br>` that contain the symbol of `:` but it doesn't work by using indexOf, why? I console nodeValue, it did selected the correct DOM.

Comment: `<br>` elements are not containers. The text in your `<dd>` will be found in separate text nodes that are children of the `<dd>`. *edit* - oh wait, sorry; you know that already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully look at the the symbol : in your strings, you will see that it is not a character `:` (colon). To check it just copy it from the string and use the `charCodeAt` method as follows:

```
'：'.charCodeAt(0)
```

It will give you 65306, which is "FULLWIDTH COLON" - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm

To search for it just replace the colon in your code with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('br').each(function () {
        var nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
        if (nodeValue.indexOf('：') > -1) {
            $(this.nextSibling).remove();
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

But it is better to use the numerical form and the comment then:

```
nodeValue.indexOf('\uFF1A') // FULLWIDTH COLON
```

Comment: in my html 3rd row is a <br> without any nodeValue, I do if nodeValue == "" to remove it, it's still there, any idea?

Comment: It is not "", it is "\n    ", so use `nodeValue.trim() == ""`

Answer (score 2):

That : is not the english :, but the Chinese one. That's why the symbol you searched is not there.